# How to use the line tool to draw a continuous line with corners in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, drawing, line-art

I'm trying to create a box with a lot of corners in it but it would be helpful if I could make the corners without having a break in the lines.  Is there a way to draw lines continuously without any breaks at all?

Comment: Pen tool? Box tool?

Comment: I said Line Tool

Comment: Yes you did but you really wanted to use pen tool. Linetool can not do what you ask but pen tool does.

Comment: Could you explain a little? Maybe it doesn't do exactly what I'm thinking

Comment: Nevermind I understand what you mean. Thanks for the feed back!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the pen tool, it does what you want as long as you click the corner point and do not attempt to drag the segment. Line tool can not make a polyline just individual lines.

Though, its also no problem to click drag multiple times and join the lines with shapebuilder or <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>j</kbd> afterward. It may seem like a extra step but given you often need to compose lines and shapes separately to do proper T-junctions for example it's not exactky as wasteful as it seems

Answer (score 0):

Actually it can be done with the line segment tool. I use Illustrator CC 2018. Draw a line anywhere on the page.  Use menu at top right to verify "Shapes" is checked.  This will bring up a little shape option in the toolbar.  "Show shape widgets" is the default.  Click it to "Hide shape widgets". Then you can use line segment tool (NOT PEN) to draw multi-line shapes.  You will still need to join the lines but it is much quicker than the pen tool.

Comment: This is a method which works, with some additional clicks, but I must say I *cannot agree* with "is much quicker than the pen tool".

Comment: Yes i use it all the time but i feel its not in the spirit of the question